# Google Kubernetes Engine: custom docker daemon.json config

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anybody know if it is possible to provide a custom daemon.json config to Docker daemon on GKE nodes?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Try to follow the ['How do I ask a good question?'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow.com and improve your question/concern for a better understanding and assistance from the community support members.

Comment: What do you want to set and why?
You can do this manually, but I would not advise it.  Also, using Docker as the container runtime is deprecated so not sure you want to go down this path in any case.

Comment: @GariSingh I'm trying to change Docker log rotation settings, in AWS I can do that by providing a custom daemon.json do Docker daemon, but in GKE looks like it is impossible.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to this.  Why exactly do you want/need to change that setting?  Have you enabled Cloud Operations (monitoring and logging) for your GKE clusters?

Comment: I cannot answer for OP, but in my case, it would definitely be useful to add an option for the docker daemon to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can update the Docker config on each node by logging into each node and modifying the Docker settings (probably easiest to modify the `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker`).  You would then need to run `kubectl drain` for that node and then restart the Docker daemon on that node.  You'd need to repeat this for each node.

That being said, why not enable Cloud Monitoring and Logging for your GKE cluster(s)?  Then you need not worry about log rotation.